# first application using vaadin with maven

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying to run my first application in Vaadin with Maven in Eclipse.
So I created new Maven Project (archetype: vaadin-archetype-application) and I'm trying to run it using Tomcat7.

and I get this error:

```
INFO: Requested resource [/VAADIN/widgetsets/pl.lajtovo.myproj.MyAppWidgetset/pl.app.myproj.MyAppWidgetset.nocache.js] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.
```

I found a website with similar problem [click](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/2541089), but I don't have in files which were generated a "web.xml".

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complaining that it's not able to find a compiled widgetset. Vaadin uses GWT on its client side. GWT makes possible to write client-side code with Java but browsers don't understand Java, so that GWT Java code must be compiled to Javascript so that browsers are able to execute it.

To compile the widgetset of your project, you can just say `mvn clean install` on the root directory of your project.

If you don't use any addons containing client-side GWT code nor you don't have your own GWT code on your project, then you could just use the standard precompiled `com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet`. Default widgetset is a precompiled widgetset that contains all core Vaadin components.

In order to use `com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet` (and avoid widgetset compilation) you need to do the following on a project that's generated from the `vaadin-archetype-application` archetype:

1. Define that you want to use default widgetset by removing the `Widgetset` annotation from your `UI`:

   `@Widgetset("com.example.MyAppWidgetset")
   public class MyUI extends UI {`
2. Add a dependency to `vaadin-client-compiled`, which contains a compiled `com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet`.

   `<dependency>
     <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
     <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
   </dependency>`
3. Remove `MyAppWidgetset.gwt.xml` from your project.

Answer (score 0):

You must compile your widgetset.

Try with
mvn install 
or
mvn vaadin:compile

See details here: https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+a+Maven+project

Comment: it doesn't change anything. I've got still this error. But when i try with vaadin-archetype-sample I get different errors.

Comment: @Lajtovo if you have compiled widgetset please describe in details how do you try to start application and what is error message.